# Boost thread finally block handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, free, boost-thread

I am porting C++ library from Windows to Linux. This is multi-threaded library. In Windows version there are `__try/__finally` block used for freeing resources and other activity after thread end. GCC doesn't support `__try/__finally` and C++ standard doesn't support it, because C++ have `RAII`. But how can i apply it to thread function?(destructor for function??).
I need to do some work then thread ended no matter which way (exception or normal return).

Is there any way to do this without writing `catch(...)` with "destructor" code and adding "destructor" code to all returns?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. I always use join() method from boost::thread to wait for particular thread end. You can also think about at_thread_exit() free method, which is called for current thread. EDIT: uuuups, I supposed you use boost library.

Comment: A __finally block will run for *any* exception, not just C++ exceptions.  There's no notion of this in Linux, it uses signals.  So using try/catch instead is as close as you ought to get.

Comment: Use [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) - it will make RAII for your.